# Author image in comments twig

Tags: theming, comments

I succesfully get user name, surname and date to render in comment.html.twig like this

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
    $comment = $variables['comment'];
    $variables['user_name_comment'] = $comment->getOwner()->field_first_name->value;
    $variables['user_surname_comment'] = $comment->getOwner()->field_last_name->value;
    $variables['created'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($variables['comment']->getCreatedTime(), 'conference_date');
}
```

In node template i got field_picture to render like this

```
$variables['author_picture'] = $node->getOwner()->field_picture->entity->url();
```

But i can't get my **field_picture** from user to render in comment twig file. I try to show the author's picture of every comment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try: $variables['author_picture'] = file_create_url($node->getOwner()->field_picture->entity>getFileUri());

Comment: nope. This breaks the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to display an entity field based on the "Manage Display" settings, you should go just `{{ content.my_field }}`. If you `"kint" content (var dump it)` you can see that each content field element has also "theme" key/property, which tells twig how to render that field

Comment: I have seen this but it doesn't seem to work. I tried also user_picture and this isn't rendering too. Btw, my settings looking grayed out in theme settings (User pictures in posts & User pictures in comments checkboxes. Both checked but i can't uncheck them).

Comment: have you tried to load user object in preprocessing and pass user picture URL in the variable?

Comment: that would bring me the image of the current user. Right? Not the owner of the comment.

Comment: every comment object having author id so you can load author and fetch author detail in a variable.

Comment: actually the comment object is loading. i am able to print author id with {{ comment.getOwnerId() }} without preprocess, but still i can't print the picture.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Create Template Preprocess Comment in your Theme file

```
function template_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
  $account = $comment->getOwner();
  $variables['user_picture'] = file_create_url($account->user_picture->entity->getFileUri());
}
```